# Cannot find module - typescript path alias error

Tags: typescript

On compile i get error that i can't fix :/

```
index.ts:2:19 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@shared'
```

Any ideas why is it?

Project structure:

[image]

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../build/backend",
  },
  "extends": "../../configs/tsconfig.base.json",
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../shared"
    }
  ],
  "paths": {
    "@shared": [
      "../shared/index"
    ]
  }
}
```

backend/index.ts:

```
import 'module-alias/register'
import { x } from '@shared'

console.log(x)
```

shared/index.ts:

```
export const x = 'this is shared index'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use this command to trace problems:

```
tsc --traceResolution
```

As i found out '@shared' is used as folder name, so it's looks like:

```
Resolving module name '@shared' relative to base url 'D:/apps/my-app/src' - 'D:/apps/my-app/src/@shared'.
```

After i changed alias to 'shared' and set baseUrl everything starts to work:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "../",
    "outDir": "../../build/backend"
  },
  "extends": "../../configs/tsconfig.base.json",
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../shared"
    }
  ],
  "paths": { "shared": ["shared/index"] }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Im having a similar problem but this doesn't seem to help. Do you think you'd be able to check my question out also please if you have time? Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67281799/typescript-aliases-not-working-properly-when-i-init-dependency

Answer (score 11):

OMG I figure it out finally.
The baseUrl and paths should be inside the compilerOptions and not outside!

Comment: Embarrassed to say I had the same issue haha. Thanks for posting this, made me realize what I was doing wrong