# Node.js Typescript - How to setup path alias

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've been struggling to setup path alias in my Node project using TypeScript. This is my `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  ...
  "dependencies": {
   ...
    "node-cache": "^5.1.2",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
   ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

`...` here is only to shorten.

Here's my `nodemon.json`:

```
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "exec": "tsc && node dist/index.js"
}
```

And finally my `tsconfig.json`, where I define a path alias under `paths`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@util/*": ["./src/util/*"],
    },
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

So if I run the following code using `npm start`

```
import logger from '@util/logger';
```

it compiles correctly using the `tsc` command but when it runs the `.js` file I get the error

`Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@util/logger' imported from /path/to/my/project/dist/index.js`.

If I replace `'@util/logger'` with `'./util/logger.js'` it works just fine, but even if I remove the `.js` it throws me the erorr, only with `Cannot find module` instead of `Cannot find package`.

Not sure what am I missing, I even tried this:

```
// index.ts
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url'; // dirname workaround
import path from 'path'; // dirname workaround
import moduleAlias from 'module-alias';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);
moduleAlias.addAliases({
  '@util': path.join(__dirname, 'util'),
});
import logger from '@util/logger';
```

but no luck, still the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript paths not working in an Express project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58187115/typescript-paths-not-working-in-an-express-project)

Answer (score 2):

What actually worked for me was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58809944/cannot-find-module-typescript-path-alias-error).

So I had to add

```
...
imports: {
   '#util/*': './dist/util/*'
}
```

to my `package.json` in order to work. But it only works with `#`, if I use `@` it thinks it's a package for some reason and throws the same error.

Comment: You can't use `@` maybe because npm uses `@` as scope?

Comment: @kennarddh yeah, maybe! But what I find odd is that almost every tutorial on path alias use `@`

Answer (score 0):

[`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) alias in `tsconfig.json` is only meant for the `tsc` compiler for types, not for the actually emitted JS code:

> Note that this feature does not change how import paths are emitted by `tsc`, so `paths` should only be used to inform TypeScript that another tool has this mapping and will use it at runtime or when bundling.

If you *do* want to also affect the runtime imports, you can use the [`tsconfig-paths`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths) library:

> Use this to load modules whose location is specified in the `paths` section of `tsconfig.json`

In your case, you could use it in your nodemon config like:

```json
{
  ...
  "exec": "tsc && node -r tsconfig-paths/register dist/index.js"
}
```

Comment: Tried with `tsconfig-paths` but no luck. What acually worked for me was this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58809944/cannot-find-module-typescript-path-alias-error)