# Cannot Find Module '@services' using Path Alias

Tags: node.js, typescript, path

This is my current file tree

[image]

The `backend` directory is in the project root along with a `client` directory. The idea here is to separate both frontend and backend in the same repository. I'm trying to access the files in the `services` directory through the `index.ts`. To do this, I set up a path alias in `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "allowJs": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "prisma/dummy.ts"],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

and I proceed to import the files as such:

`import { contactService } from "@/services";`

But when I run the server I get the following error:

`[ERROR] 09:18:28 Error: Cannot find module '@/services'`

How can I configure the path alias so that TS can read my imports using the path alias?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76765386/5108796